# Using Neo4jUserManager

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, neo4j, asp.net-identity-2, neo4jclient

I'm new at Neo4j and I'm going to use neo4j.AspNet.Identity for my authentication and authorization. I'm using neo4jUserManager and also neo4jUserStore.But when I run the application, in Neo4jUserManager create method I'll face with NullExceptionReference and I don't know why? Can Anybody help me? 
Below is my code

```
 public class Neo4jUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public Neo4jUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }

    public async Task SetLastLogin()
    {
        //            Store.FindByIdAsync()
    }

    public static Neo4jUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<Neo4jUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        var graphClientWrapper = context.Get<GraphClientWrapper>();
        var manager = new Neo4jUserManager(new Neo4jUserStore<ApplicationUser>(graphClientWrapper.GraphClient));

        // Configure validation logic for usernames
        //            manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<Neo4jUser>(manager)
        //            {
        //                AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
        //                RequireUniqueEmail = true
        //            };

        manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true
        };

        // Configure user lockout defaults
        manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = false;
        manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;

        // Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user
        // You can write your own provider and plug it in here.
        //            manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Phone Code", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<Neo4jUser>
        //            {
        //                MessageFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
        //            });
        //            manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Email Code", new EmailTokenProvider<Neo4jUser>
        //            {
        //                Subject = "Security Code",
        //                BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
        //            });
        //            manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
        //            manager.SmsService = new SmsService();
        var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            manager.UserTokenProvider =
                new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
        }
        return manager;
    }
}
```

Comment: Firstly - What is the stacktrace of your error. Secondly - How do you setup the `GraphClientWrapper`. If you're getting a `NullReferenceException`, the something is `null`. You should easily be able to find this out. As you're using the version of `Neo4j.AspNet.Identity` that contains `Neo4jUserManager` you *have* to be using the source code and not a nuget package - so it should be even easier to debug.

Comment: I use source code and reference it to my project, and stack trace message is {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."} . can u help me if I want to use Neo4jUserManager what should I do? I mean I don't know how to setup `GraphClientWrapper`  @ChrisSkardon

Comment: No, that's *not* a stack trace, that's the message. What is the stack trace, where *exactly* is the error thrown. I'm guessing as you don't know how to Setup `GraphClientWrapper` that your `graphClientWrapper` var is null?

Comment: Yeah I don't know how to setup `GraphClientWrapper` and so `graphClientWrapper` is null,can you help me how to setup `GraphClientWrapper`? @ChrisSkardon

Comment: Thanks alot beacuse of your guidance,I undrestand somewhat but in `ConfigureAuth.cs` file I should add this line of code `app.CreatePerOwinContext(GraphClientWrapper.create); `and also this line `app.CreatePerOwinContext<Neo4jUserManager>(Neo4jUserManager.Create);` but `GraphClient` doesn't have any create method should I change the code and rebuild the dll OR I am in a wrong way? Can you help me one more time? @ChrisSkardon

Answer (score 1):

To setup the `graphClientWrapper`, you can do this:

```
var gc = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost.:7474/db/data"));
gc.Connect();
var graphClientWrapper = new GraphClientWrapper(gc);
var manager = new Neo4jUserManager(new Neo4jUserStore<ApplicationUser>(graphClientWrapper.GraphClient));
```

Also, as a side I would read up on how to use Owin. It should have been obvious to you that you're trying to pull from an `IOwinContext` object, and that if you're getting `null` you should investigate how to set that up. I imagine less than 5 minutes on Google would have helped you. **OR** just looking at what calls that method would have shown you how the `EntityFramework` was being setup in the template you're modifying.

Comment: Thanks alot beacuse of your guidance,I undrestand somewhat but in `ConfigureAuth.cs` file I should add this line of code `app.CreatePerOwinContext(GraphClientWrapper.create);` and also this line `app.CreatePerOwinContext<Neo4jUserManager>(Neo4jUserManager.Create);` but GraphClient doesn't have any create method should I change the code and rebuild the dll **OR** I am in a wrong way? Can you help me one more time? @ChrisSkardon

Comment: Read up on Owin, I'm not going to explain any more, as I've had 3 people in the last 24 hours ask exactly the same thing (including yourself) directly to my email address, leading me to think this is something like homework.